# Select instruments visible in each system in MuseScore

Tags: engraving, musescore

I am inputting notes where the choir comes in system 2, so system 1 should only contain piano notes. How do I hide the choir in the first system?

Comment: Not checked myself, but see [this link](https://musescore.org/en/node/2319) and [this link](https://musescore.org/en/node/22158).

Comment: If this helps any searches along the way, this is often called a "Frenched staff" or "Frenched score."

Comment: Googling `musescore +frenched` gives no hit.

Comment: @AndersLindén I don't quite understand the question. I have MuseScore at hand, but what do you mean by "hide"? If you have 2 systems, they should each have different notes unless you specifically need to double the notes.

Answer (score 1):

In MuseScore 3.6 to get a "Frenched score" (i.e. to hide the empty staves in a system)

1. Click on "Format" in the menu, and go down down to the "Style" submenu item.
2. Open the "Score" dialog, then
   a) check the "Hide empty staves within systems" checkbox,  and
   b) uncheck the "Don't hide empty staves in the first system" checkbox.